# Call function in applicationdidbecomeactive - Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift

So, I've got a func in my GameScene.swift file that I'd like to call every time my game becomes active. Currently I'm running this function in didMoveToView in my GameScene.swift file but it only runs when the app launches after being completely closed and I'd like to do it every time the game becomes active. (user hits home button and then re-opens app)

I assume running the func in applicationdidbecomeactive in the AppDelegate.swift file would work but I'm not sure how to do this or if it's actually possible. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It might help to mention that this func is only changing some SKSpriteNode textures like so... backgroundSprite.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed:"tempBG") so if there is another way of changing the textures when the app becomes active I'm all ears. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add an observer in your GameScene.swift for `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` and call your function. e.g.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, 
selector: #selector(GameScene.yourfunction,
name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
```

Comment: #selector is now the appropriate way to write a selector.

Comment: That did it! Thanks!

Comment: **SWIFT 3** update: `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.checkBundleSettings(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)` and the method is: `func checkBundleSettings(notification: Notification){...your method}`

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, post a NSNotification in applicationdidbecomeactive in the AppDelegate.

```
let nc = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
nc.postNotificationName("didBecomeActive", object: nil)
```

Then, attach a listener to your GameScene.swift file.

```
let nc = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
nc.addObserver(self, selector: "didBecomeActive", name: "didBecomeActive", object: nil)
```

Finally, implement the selector "didBecomeActive"

```
func didBecomeActive(notification:NSNotification) {
    //Call your function here 
    //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's **SWIFT 5** update based on @firstinq answer

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MainViewController.appDidBecomeActive), name:UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
```